# React JS state change doesn't re-render the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one main component as follows :

```
render() {
    const language = this.props.language.default.portal;

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="searchLeft noPadding col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-5">
                <Price language={language} actionFilters={this.props.actionFilters} allCarsInTheList={this.props.carsToShow}/>

            </div>
            <div className="contentRight noPadding col-xl-10 col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-7">
                <div className="filterBar">
                    <SmallFilters language={language} filters={this.props.filters} allCarsInTheList={this.props.carsToShow} actionFilters={this.props.actionFilters}/>                       
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

My price component is as follows :

```
export default class PriceRangeFilter extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        range: {
            low: _.min(this.props.allCarsInTheList.map (i => i.price)),
            high: _.max(this.props.allCarsInTheList.map (i => i.price)),
            active: false
        }
    };
}

handleFilter(){
    if(this.state.range.active){
        this.props.actionFilters.addPriceRangeFilter(this.state.range);
    }else{
        this.props.actionFilters.removePriceRangeFilter();
    }
}

changeFilter(range) {
    this.setState({range: range}, this.handleFilter);
}

deActivate(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let n_range = this.state.range;
    n_range.active = false;
    this.changeFilter(n_range);
}

renderSmall() {
    return (
        <div key={this.props.key} className="filter">
            {this.props.title} <Link to="" onClick={this.deActivate.bind(this)}><FontAwesome name="times" className="portalFaRedIcon"/></Link>
        </div>
    );
}

render(){
    const language = this.props.language;
    if(this.props.recap) return this.renderSmall();
    console.log(this.state.range);
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="priceTitle">{language.price}</div>
            <SliderRange language={language}
                         range={this.state.range}
                         min={_.min(this.props.allCarsInTheList.map (i => i.price))}
                         max={_.max(this.props.allCarsInTheList.map (i => i.price))}
                         step={data.configuration.PRICE_RANGE_STEP}
                         sign="€"
                         type="price"
                         onChange={this.changeFilter.bind(this)} />
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

And my SmallFilters component is as follows :

```
import PriceFilter from './price';


class filters extends React.Component {

    checkFilter(name, filters){
        return filters.some(f => name == f.name);
    }

    showFilter(filters){
        if(this.checkFilter(filter_names.priceRange, filters)){
            return <PriceFilter recap={this.checkFilter(filter_names.priceRange, filters)} title="Price" allCarsInTheList={this.props.allCarsInTheList} actionFilters={this.props.actionFilters}/>
        }
    }

    render(){
        const language = this.props.language;
        const filters = this.props.filters;
        return (
            <div className="filters noPadding col-xl-8 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionAppear={true} transitionAppearTimeout={500} transitionEnterTimeout={500} transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
                    {this.showFilter(filters)}
                </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

The problem is in the SmallFilters component. I include there the same Price component as in the Search component. Then, in the price component I return `renderSmall` function if `this.props.recap` is true.

When I click on the link inside `renderSmall` to deactivate the filter it should update the state. But the state isn't changed. `this.state.range.active` stays true.

Any advice?

**UPDATE**

SliderRange component code is as follows :

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {formatNumber} from './formatNumber';

export default class SliderRange extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = this.getStateFromProps(this.props);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
        this.setState(this.getStateFromProps(newProps));
    }

    getStateFromProps(props) {
        return {
            low: props.range.low,
            high: props.range.high,
            active: props.range.active
        };
    }

    numberWithSpace(number) {
        return (this.props.type == "year") ? number : formatNumber(number);
    }


    handleChange(low, high, active) {
        let n_active = active;
        if(low!=this.state.low) n_active = true;
        if(high!=this.state.high) n_active = true;
        if(low == this.props.min && high == this.props.max) n_active = false;
        const result = {
            low: low,
            high: high,
            active: n_active
        };
        this.props.onChange(result);
    }

    handleActive(event) {
        const checkbox = event.target.checked;
        let low = this.state.low;
        let high = this.state.high;
        if(checkbox && this.state.low == this.props.min && this.state.high == this.props.max) {
            low = this.props.min + this.props.step;
            high = this.props.max - this.props.step;

        }else{
            low = this.props.min;
            high = this.props.max;
        }
        this.handleChange(low, high, checkbox);
    }

    handleLow(event) {
        if(parseInt(event.target.value) < parseInt(this.state.high)){
            this.handleChange(event.target.value, this.state.high, this.state.active);
        }
    }

    handleHigh(event) {
        if(parseInt(event.target.value) > parseInt(this.state.low)) {
            this.handleChange(this.state.low, event.target.value, this.state.active);
        }
    }

    render() {
        const sign = this.props.sign;
        const min = this.props.min;
        const max = this.props.max;
        const step = this.props.step;


        const low = this.state.low;
        const high = this.state.high;
        const active = this.state.active;

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="rangeValues">Range : {this.numberWithSpace(low)} {sign} - {this.numberWithSpace(high)} {sign}</div>
                <section className="range-slider">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked={active} onChange={this.handleActive.bind(this)}/>
                    <input type="range" name="first" value={low} min={min} max={max} step={step}  onChange={this.handleLow.bind(this)} className="firstRange"/>
                    <input type="range" name="second" value={high} min={min} max={max} step={step} onChange={this.handleHigh.bind(this)} className="secondRange"/>
                    <div className="minValue">{this.numberWithSpace(min)} {sign}</div>
                    <div className="maxValue">{this.numberWithSpace(max)} {sign}</div>
                </section>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

SliderRange.propTypes = {
    language: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    range: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    min: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    max: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    step: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete I guess. I see PriceRangeFilter's inital value of active is false, and when you deactivate, it is set to false again. Nowhere the code sets active to true.

Comment: Yes. I updated my question.

Comment: Does deActivate get called when you click the link of renderSmall()? If yes, then put console.log statement at all place where active can change and check whether anything is setting it back to true or not.

Comment: If I put `console.log(this.state.range)`in the render and in the else statement of the handleFilter, in render I get `active: true` and in handleFilter `active: false`.

Comment: Yes, so it is working right? In the question you said "this.state.range.active stays true.". It's changing to false.

However I am not sure why active = true, in the beginning. Maybe 'recap' was false at some point of time.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing a nested property. Try creating a new object using Object.assign() as follows:

```
deActivate(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let n_range = Object.assign({}, this.state.range);
    n_range.active = false;
    this.changeFilter(n_range);
}
```

Comment: No, still the same problem.